# MongoDB atlas through mongo shell: "Error: bad auth : Authentication failed." what could possibly cause this Authentication failure?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, authentication, mongoose

I have a problem connecting to MongoDB atlas through mongo shell, even though I have done everything right and triple checked data username and password, included my IP in the whitelist, changed the database name to test, and tried adding --password in the same line

`$ mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster******.mongodb.net/test" --username admin --password admin
MongoDB shell version v4.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00.4d5jd.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.4d5jd.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.4d5jd.mongodb.net:27017/test?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&ssl=true

*** You have failed to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.

Error: bad auth : Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1`

Comment: Can you access the page www.portquiz.net:27017 ? it checks if you have a firewall. If you do, then the problem is on Atlas. Go to your Atlas cluster -> Network tab -> white list all IPs adding **0.0.0.0** to the field

Comment: Also, if you share your cluster subdomain: `cluster0.4d5jd` people are likely to hack you, so better never share that data.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: `Error: bad auth : Authentication failed...` - generally means wrong userid / password. have you tried connecting to your Atlas cluster using any other tools like Compass?

Comment: I accessed "www.portquiz.net:27017" everything is good there and add 0.0.0.0 including my IP address to the whitelist.//

cluster subdomain removed thank you so much!

I have tried connecting using Compass keeps trying to connect until it gives Timeout Error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB Atlas creates all users in the admin database.

The output from your attempt does not indicate that it was using the admin database for authentication, so you will likely need to use either the `--authenticationDatabase` command line option, or include `authSource=` in the URL, i.e. one of:

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster******.mongodb.net/test" --username admin --password admin --authenticationDatabase admin
```

or

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster******.mongodb.net/test?authSource=admin" --username admin --password admin
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great help, Joe!  I really appreciate the effort.
The first link worked and connected me to Atlas thank you so much!

Comment: But it gives "MongoDB Enterprise atlas-65olkl-shard-0:SECONDARY>" not primary is it ok to give SECONDARY because it doesn't take "show dbs" command

Comment: That seems a bit odd, try adding `&replicaSet=atlas-65olkl-shard-0` to the URL

Comment: IT WORKED thank you so much, Joe !!!  I really appreciate the help, I just wish that I can understand those things you helped me with. 
Again thank you so much!